# Stroking an SVG polyline with a gradient

Tags: svg, gradient

Is it possible to stroke an SVG polyline with an horizontal linear gradient where the gradient's angle changes at every polyline vertex? it would look something like this:
[image]

Comment: Better yet, look at <replicate> at http://srufaculty.sru.edu/david.dailey/svg/SVGOpen2010/replicate.htm -- It does do this declaratively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [tubefy](http://owl3d.com/svg/tubefy/articles/) by Israel Eisenberg. There's not currently anything in svg that will give you exactly what you're asking for declaratively. However, tubefy makes use of svg for rendering, and can produce advanced gradients such as the one you're looking for.