# Java2D gradient line stroke

Tags: java, canvas, graphics, awt, java-2d

I would like to stroke a line with a gradient that follows the line direction:

[image: Gradient example]

Is it possible to achieve this with Java 2D? If not then what other Java libraries would you recommend?

Comment: Not sure if its possible built in, did you try drawing a line directly next to it? or a rectangle around it?

Comment: does this question help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295736/stroking-an-svg-polyline-with-a-gradient ?